# Input function converts the input into string so that is why my list input does not work

Tags: python, list

The function sort on the basis of the sum of matrix in the list
This function works well If I don't take input from user.
Input should is like [[4,5,6],[6,7,9]]
what should I do that it takes input like above from user and don't show any error

```
def sort_function(your_list):
    ans = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)
     #Using sort function to sort the list on the basis of the sum of the inner number of matrix
    print(ans)
sort_function(your_list=list(input("Please enter a matrix of any dimension : ")))
```

I think input function is converting the input into string how should I convert it back into list like input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you've asked two questions. I'll address the second question first:

#### Make the function return a list

> I think input function is converting the input into string how should I convert it back into list like input?

Your `sort_function` is indeed converting your `list` input into something that's not a list. In fact, it's not actually converting it to a string, because your `sort_function` *returns* **nothing**. It only *prints* things to screen.

Easy mistake to make; if it's not clear to you what I mean, try this in IPython, and ask yourself what you think is stored in the variable `t`:

```py
s = "hello"
t = print(s)
```

So to fix your `sort_function`, you need it to return a value. This is probably what you want:

```py
def sort_function(your_list):
    ans = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)
    return ans
```

In IPython, you should give it a go with something like this:

```py
data = [[9, 0], [1,2,3], [-100, 88]] 
s = sort_function(data)
print(s)
# Out[]: [[9, 0], [1, 2, 3], [-100, 88]]
```

#### How to read input from user

> Input should is like [[4,5,6],[6,7,9]] what should I do that it takes input like above from user and don't show any error

So I saved your first question for last because it's a lot harder (dealing with user input is always hard) and it requires knowing a lot about what your intent is, and overall experience in software engineering...and that's honestly too complicated for a single StackOverflow q&a

But my advice to you is that you should **not** be requiring/expecting your user to enter input in Python list syntax. Not only is that hugely inconvenient to the user, but converting that string input (because that's what `"[[4,5,6],[6,7,9]]"` is: a string) into a list will almost certainly require a huge amount of technical work and/or adding **severe** security flaws into your application (e.g. using `eval()` in this situation is a **very bad** idea, and anyone who sees it would not have much respect for you).

Instead, you should rethink the input format asked of the user. Instead of asking for `"[1,2,3]"`, why not `"1,2,3"`? The latter can be converted into a list of numbers like this:

```py
data = []

user_input = '1,2,3'
d = [int(x) for x in user_input.split(',')]
data.append(d)

user_input = '20,-5'
d = [int(x) for x in user_input.split(',')]
data.append(d)

sorteddata = sort_function(data)
print(sorteddata)
# [[20, -5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I leave it to you to figure out how to simplify the above by using a `for` loop and functions, e.g. a loop that asks the user for a list of numbers, until the user enters 'END' or something...

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza list por eval:

```
sort_function(your_list=eval(input("Please enter a matrix of any dimension : ")))
```

or use json.loads

```
import json
sort_function(your_list=json.loads(input("Please enter a matrix of any dimension : ")))
```

Comment: This will work but I would just like to add. `eval` is very dangerous since it will execute any python code that is entered into it. So if its just you inputting things then its fine but if you pass in input from an unknown source be very careful.

Comment: So, you can use json.loads to convert string to list

Comment: Yea, json is probably the better one to use. Simple one liner to convert string to any number of nested lists. This should be the accepted answer. +1